# How can I specify entry-point class and jar archive for JBCO (Java ByteCode Obfuscator)?

Tags: java, obfuscation

I can't guess how can I specify class, which is entry-point of my program (therefore shouldn't be obfuscated), and my jar archive. Please show me an command-line example, how to use [JBCO](http://www.sable.mcgill.ca/JBCO/) when I have /home/example/myJar.jar and within it com.example.EntryPoint class and my external dependency /home/example/dependencies/dependencyJar.jar.

Also, please, does anybody know if this project is still alive and what jdk it supports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of time have passed, but recently I have passed across the java transformation frameworks and find out that JBCO now is a part of soot framework, [hosted](https://github.com/Sable/soot) on GitHub, but it is `@deprecated` as for now. There is a [wiki](https://github.com/Sable/soot/wiki) where you can get more info about how to use soot/jbco (if you still want to, on your own risk, even though JBCO is deprecated and not under active development it still from time to time accepts PRs from contributors).
As for the command line options it might be:

```
java -cp .:/home/example/sootclasses-trunk-jar-with-dependencies.jar soot.jbco.Main -process-dir /home/example/compiled -output-dir /home/example/obfuscated -soot-class-path .:/home/example/myJar.jar -output-format class -app -main-class com.example.EntryPoint -t:9:wjtp.jbco_cr
```

Soot can process your compiled code as class files (then pass it to `-process-dir` option) or as jar (then pass it as part of soot-class-path) - soot can process many forms of bytecode (java/scala/.. bytecode, android bytecode, jasmin, jimple). There are also options to specify what is library classes and application or argument classes more precisely, for more info please refer to soot's wiki page.